# I can't override the user_pass hook

Tags: users

because I use a websevcice to manage my users, I need to override the user_pass() to send a new password via my webservices.
This is what i did:

```
/**
* Implements hook_validate()
*/
function beneficiaire_user_pass_validate($form, &$form_state){
    die('poc');
}

/**
* Implements hook_submit()
*/
function beneficiaire_user_pass_submit($form, &$form_state){
    module_load_include('inc', 'beneficiaire', 'ws');
    global $user;

    if(beneficiaire_reset_password($user->name)){
        drupal_goto('login');
    }
}
```

My module is named beneficiaire.
I've cleaned my caches many times
when I enter a username in the form, it returns me

> Sorry, %name is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address

instead of

> poc

An idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is that, since your module's short name is beneficiaire, those are the implementations of `hook_user_pass_validate()` and `hook_user_pass_submit()`, which aren't hook Drupal utilizes. If you rename the functions `beneficiaire_validate()` and `beneficiaire_submit()`, those would not be hooks which are used as validation and submission handlers for the password change form.
See @Clive's answer for how adding form validation and submission handlers, keeping in mind that the validation handler is added with `$form['#validate'][] = 'beneficiaire_user_pass_validate';`.

As side notes:

- If you want to check a validation handler is called, use `form_set_error("", "beneficiaire_user_pass_validate() called");`
- To redirect the user after submitting a form, set `$form_state['redirect']` as in `$form_state['redirect'] = 'login';`

Answer (score 2):

`hook_validate()` is for modules that provide content types, not for hooking into normal forms.

What you're looking for is `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, something similar to this:

```
function beneficiaire_form_user_pass_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'beneficiaire_user_pass_submit';
}

function beneficiaire_user_pass_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
}
```